# What's the name for this unimodal sequence?

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, reference-request

Let $a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n$ be an increasing sequence of positive numbers, and consider the sequence $s_1,\ldots,s_n$, where
$$
s_k \;=\; \frac{a_0+\cdots + a_k}{k}.
$$
So
$$
s_1 \;=\; a_0+a_1,\quad s_2=\frac{a_0+a_1+a_2}{2},\quad s_3=\frac{a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3}{3},\quad \ldots
$$
It's not hard to show that this sequence is unimodal — it decreases and then increases.   I recently ran into a combinatorics problem whose answer was the minimum value of this sequence:
$$
m \;=\; \min\{s_1,\ldots,s_n\}.
$$
It seems to me that this should be a well-known thing in enumerative combinatorics, but I haven't had much luck with Google.

> **Question:** Is there a standard name for either the sequence $s_1,\ldots,s_n$ itself or its minimum value $m$?  Are there any well-known combinatorial problems in which this sequence arises?

Note that the minimum value can also be defined as
$$
\min_{B\subseteq A}\frac{\sum B}{|B| - 1}
$$
where $A$ is the set $\{a_0,\ldots,a_n\}$.

Comment: I think math overflow is more likely to locate what you're looking for.

Comment: The $s_k$ look like Cesaro means.

Comment: For the name of $(s_n)$, you may want to refer to the [Cesàro mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean).

Comment: It is exactly Cesaro mean if $a_0=0$.

Comment: The sequence is actually $s_n = c_n (n+1)/n$ where $c_n$ is the Cesaro mean sequence.

Comment: "it decreases..." only if $a_0+a_1>a_2$

Comment: @leonbloy If $a_0 + a_1 \leq a_2$, then the sequence is monotonically increasing.  It is also possible for the sequence to be monotonically decreasing.